# Js text scrolling from list is limited in size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a demo setup here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqWxvm

Where is the limit set in this javascript of the amount of text that scroll, it currently doesn't show the whole content of the `li`

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
}); 
jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
      travelocity: 0.17
    }, settings);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $strip = jQuery(this);
        $strip.addClass("newsticker")
        var stripWidth = 1;

        $strip.find("li").each(function(i) {
            stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
        });

        var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
        var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
        var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width(); //a.k.a. 'mask' width    
        $strip.width(stripWidth);
        var totalTravel = stripWidth + containerWidth;
        var defTiming = totalTravel / settings.travelocity; // thanks to Scott Waye     

        function scrollnews(spazio, tempo) {
            $strip.animate({
              left: '-=' + spazio
            }, tempo, "linear", function() {
              $strip.css("left", containerWidth);
              scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
            });
        }

        scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
        $strip.hover(function() {
           jQuery(this).stop();
        },
         function() {
            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
            var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
            scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know javascript very well, so I can't answer - however, stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); << that line is only returning the width of the container, rather than the width (in pixels) of the string.  To see what I'm talking about, if you add a large number to this, you'll scroll the whole string.  

Hopefully that will at least help.

Comment: What are you asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify CSS with these lines :

```
.tickercontainer .mask {width: 1300px !important;}
#ticker01 {float: left; width: auto !important; }
```

You can play with "width" property to show elements.